# Posts XML to Play Framework controller but asXml() is always null

Tags: xml, playframework, controller

I have a very simple controller.

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Xml.class)
public static Result Event() {
    Http.RequestBody body = request().body();
    Logger.debug(body.toString());
    return ok("Got XML:" + body.asXml());
}
```

The problem is that asXml() is always null. I post with Postman and Content-Type is application/xml. I also tried [the curl from the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaXmlRequests).

If I change to BodyParse.Json.class and post JSON it works like a charm.

[image: Screenshot from IntelliJ]

Play Framework 2.2.x.

Comment: Make sure you pass correct `Content-Type`.

Comment: I have made that very sure and that why the XML shows up in the middle of the screenshot. The problem is that asXml is null anyway.